# Get item from folder with nodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, express

Is there any way to get Item from local server folder?

Lets say I have a folder in my project which contains pictures and I want to get all of them

Is it possible to pass path to folder in URL params like this ?

```
 app.get('/getPicture/:path',(req,res)=>{
    // .... 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the `express.static`-middleware and don't need a separate request-handler for this:

```
app.use(express.static('./path/to/image/folder'));
```

With that the client can load all files within that folder, see https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html for further details.